# ASP.NET Session always affect by datatable variable

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session

Here is my code

```
    Dim dtX As DataTable
    dtX = Session("dtCustomer")

    For i As Integer = dtX.Rows.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If isValid(dtX.Rows(i)("id")) = true Then
            dtX.Rows.RemoveAt(i)
        End If
    Next
```

My problem is while the program running the "dtX.Rows.RemoveAt(i)" line, the data stored in session get updated too. How to prevent session be affected while I removing rows in datatable? It shouldn't happen right?

Need your help guys, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens (as it should) because `dtX` is a reference to the same `DataTable` instance that is stored in `Session`.

If you need to operate on a copy of `DataTable` without affecting the instance in `Session`, add

```
dtX = dtX.Copy()
```

after

```
dtX = Session("dtCustomer")
```